# Which word to use in this sentence, "when" or "which"?

Tags: grammar, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Bolt took his first shot at success on the world stage at the 2002 World Junior Championships in Kingston, Jamaica, ***when/where*** he won the 200-meter dash.

Should we use when or where in this sentence? 
Thanks a lot : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Where*** should be used here; the focus is on the event (*the 2002 World Junior Championships*), rather than the time period. Had the event and location been omitted, and only the time given (“*Bolt took his first shot at success in 2002, ...”*), ***when*** would be used, as the focus now becomes the time period.